# como aumentar el 3% del iva con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

trato de agregar la suma del 3% del iva que se debe colocar en cuanto yo hago una suma
ejemplo

20.99 * 2 (unidades)
=41.98 +3% iva

como tal la forma que supose era la siguiente
por un input post
mando lo que es la $suma
que la suma es por medio de otro input que ya tiene el valor del numero y otro que se va escribir el nuevo valor comopor ejemplo 2 o 3
la cuestion es que me sale asi en monto a pagar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta mi codigo de el que saca el porcentaje

```
<?php
$sdo_total=3;
                $cnv =(1-(floatval($suma) /$sdo_total)) *100;

echo $cnv;

?>
```

Comment: No terminé de entender la operación que necesitas hacer. ¿A qué refieres con el 3% del iva? Es decir, en México el IVA de una cantidad es el 16% del monto total...

Comment: mas viene le debe sumar el 3% es de venta diamantes de frefire y videojuegosjuegos

Comment: Ok. ¿Entonces si el monto fuera de 1000, el resultado final de sumar el 3% sería 1030?

Comment: pues si seria correcto pero serian con decimales ya que son en dolares

Comment: Con esto le sumas el por ciento de `$iva` al precio: **`$precio *= (1 + $iva / 100);`**

Answer (score 4):

Si tenemos un caso en que la cantidad del monto total fuera de `1345.60` y queremos sumarle el 3% al monto, con PHP haríamos lo siguiente:

```
<?php

//puedes después cambiarlo a 16% si así lo requieres, de momento el valor del iva es de 3%
$valor_iva = 3;
$monto_total = 1345.60;
$resultado = ( $monto_total ) + ( $monto_total * ( $valor_iva / 100 ) );
// el resultado sería 1,345.60 que es 1345.60 más el 3% que equivale a 40.368

//En caso de que quieras redondear a dos decimales, te recomiendo usar la función number_format

$resultado = number_format($resultado, 2, '.', false);

echo $resultado;
```

Puedes leer más información sobre la función `number_format` [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Con algo como esto sumarías el 3% a un valor dado:

```
$totalPrice *= (1 + $iva / 100);
```

Aquí, `$totalPrice` sería tu precio total (sin IVA), mientras que `$iva` sería el porcentaje aplicable.

Si te interesa guardar tanto el valor sin IVA como con IVA, puedes usar un array. (Esto sería particularmente útil si necesitaras transportar `$mPrices` a otra parte o lo necesitaras como `return` de una función).

Por ejemplo:

```
$totalPrice=20.99*2;
$iva = 3;
$mPrices['sinIVA']=$totalPrice;
$mPrices['conIVA']=$totalPrice *= (1 + $iva / 100);
echo "Sin IVA\t:   ".number_format($mPrices['sinIVA'],2).PHP_EOL;
echo "$iva% IVA\t: ".number_format($mPrices['conIVA'],2);
```

**Salida:**

```
Sin IVA : 41.98
3% IVA  : 43.24
```

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar un % adicional a un valor puedes hacer la siguiente formula:

```
$total = $subtotal * 1.03
```

El 1,03 indicas que agregarás un 3% adicional al valor total ya obtenido,

Otro ejemplo.
¿Quieres agregar un 50%?, ej:

```
$total = $subtotal * 1.5
```

¿Quieres agregar un 9%?, ej:

```
$total = $subtotal * 1.09
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: lo acavo de probar y me dice que no esperaba una coma ,

Comment: lo deje asi --- <?php
$total = $suma * 1,03;


echo $total;

?>

Comment: Ups disculpa, prueba con un ., ejemplo: $total = $subtotal * 1.03;

Comment: ya quedo te ganaste mi voto y hay forma de que en pantalla solo imprima a dos digitos porque lo muestra asi  -->  21.6197

Comment: Esto solamente servira cuando el monto sea 1000, debes agregar un valor `iva` y un valor `total` para hacer la operacion

Comment: Si, puedes usar la función round($total,2), o number_format($total,2), te recomiendo usar la primera para redondear los dígitos significativos

Comment: @Rmendoza Revisa si mi respuesta te fue útil y si te sirvió te sugiero marcarla como la respuesta correcta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer lago mas simple.

```
$valor = 20.99; //valor producto
$cantidad = 2; //cantidad
$iva = 1.03; // 3% de iva

$resultadouno = $valor * $cantidad;
$impuesto = $resultadouno * $iva;

echo number_format($impuesto, 2, '.', false);
```

Resultado $43.24